# Extjs 4 Socket.io Proxy

Tags: extjs, web-applications, socket.io, extjs4

I'm working on a project that uses Node.js as server and the client is a webapp developed using Ext JS 4.2.

The communication protocol relies on the Socket.io library.

I was trying to integrate the socket.io communication in my webapp in a way that is as much as possible polished and compliant to the Ext JS 4's MVC.

The first idea I had was to have a class that was looking like [THIS](https://github.com/mrsunshine/Mobile-Chat-with-Sencha-Touch---node.js---socket.io-/blob/master/js/lib/App.util.Socketio.js) that basically has all the socket.io callbacks which will get the needed Ext JS elements and set the received data to them.

However i saw that ExtJS 4 introduces the concept of Proxy and Stores and I was thinking if what I need can be achieved using these functionalities (I'm a beginner with extjs 4).

Long story made short: What's in your opinion the best practice to handle this scenario? Also: even if it's possible to achieve what I need with proxies/stores, will it be easier and at the same time a good pratice using them in this case or the callbacks way is fine enough?

Any other solution is welcomed.